# VBA word restart numbering at 1after each heading

Tags: vba, loops, ms-word, formatting, number-formatting

I have a piece of code for a word document that reads its own table of contents and then searches a particular folder for a word document related to each heading. It then copies the contents and pastes it under the appropriate heading. However, these pieces of text are in the form of a numbers list and when they are pasted in, the numbering continues from the previous heading and won't restart at 1. I have tried a few different pieces of code, which I found my recording a macro and I had it where it changed the first number but then from the second number it continued from the last. I feel that I probably need a loop to iterate through the numbers list but I am not sure how to implement this. I would really appreciate any help with this as I am out of ideas. 
Thank you in advance!

Robbie
Sub InsertRoomDocumentFile()

'Declare variables
     Dim a As String
     Dim header As String
     Dim f As String
     Dim sourceDocument As Document
     Dim tocItems As Variant
     Dim myField As Field

```
Set sourceDocument = ActiveDocument
```

'Call Table of contents function
    tocItems = GetTOCItems

```
a = "\\HEADFOP002V\ST_Dolan_R$\windows\Desktop\"
f = ".docx"
'Print table of contents to window
counter = 0
For Each myField In sourceDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Fields
   'Debug.Print myField.result.Text ', Chr(13), "-") & " " & " Type: " & myField.Type
    If counter <> 0 Then
       header = myField.result.Text
       Debug.Print header
       Total = a + header + f
       Documents.Open FileName:=Total, ReadOnly:=True
           Set myWindow = Windows(1)
           winNum = myWindow.Index
           If Windows.Count >= 2 Then
               ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
               Selection.WholeStory
               ActiveDocument.Range(WholeStory).Copy
               myWindow.Close
               If counter = 1 Then
                    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst
                    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToRelative, Count:=1
               Else
                    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext
                    Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToRelative, Count:=1
               End If

             Selection.Range.Paste

             End If
    End If
  DoEvents
  counter = counter + 1
Next
```

End Sub

This is the macro I recorded to restart the numbering. I have included the Selection.Range.Paste line to show you where I put it into my code.

```
                Selection.Range.Paste                                                            'Paste the copied file under the appropriate heading

With ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).ListLevels(1)
    .NumberFormat = "(%1)"
    .TrailingCharacter = wdTrailingTab
    .NumberStyle = wdListNumberStyleArabic
    .NumberPosition = CentimetersToPoints(-1.27)
    .Alignment = wdListLevelAlignLeft
    .TextPosition = CentimetersToPoints(-0.27)
    .TabPosition = wdUndefined
    .ResetOnHigher = 0
    .StartAt = 1
    With .Font
        .Bold = wdUndefined
        .Italic = wdUndefined
        .StrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Subscript = wdUndefined
        .Superscript = wdUndefined
        .Shadow = wdUndefined
        .Outline = wdUndefined
        .Emboss = wdUndefined
        .Engrave = wdUndefined
        .AllCaps = wdUndefined
        .Hidden = wdUndefined
        .Underline = wdUndefined
        .Color = wdUndefined
        .Size = wdUndefined
        .Animation = wdUndefined
        .DoubleStrikeThrough = wdUndefined
        .Name = ""
    End With
    .LinkedStyle = ""
End With
ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1).Name = ""
Selection.Range.ListFormat.ApplyListTemplate ListTemplate:= _
    ListGalleries(wdNumberGallery).ListTemplates(1), ContinuePreviousList:= _
    False, ApplyTo:=wdListApplyToWholeList, DefaultListBehavior:= _
    wdWord10ListBehavior
```

Comment: It would be useful if you had your peace of code in your question

Comment: An option:
a=1
do until a = numberoflist
---do whatewer you need

a=a+1
loop

Comment: Hi Salek, Thank you for getting back to me. I am sorry I didn't put the code in initially. However, when I try to put it in now it says that there are too many characters. Would I need to put the whole code in? I am trying to restart these numbers after a line that says Selection.Range.Paste. If this is a ridiculous question let me know and I will try to put the code in. I will also try your suggestion first though so thank you for that. Should this be a while loop or do I just use I as it is. I am new to this VBA so sorry about these questions.

Comment: Hi. I think the part with numbering (like start of your loop and the end if it, whereever you use numbering) will be enough

Comment: Hi Salek, Thanks again for your reply. I don't have a loop for that as I copy the text (which is already numbered form 1 to whatever)  from another document and then when I paste it into my document using Selection.Range.Paste it just continues numbering from the numbering of the previous heading. I have my first version of this code that I will put up now that may show what I am trying to do. After it says Selection.Range.Paste this pastes into my main document. I then want to restart the numbering at one each time I paste. I will put the code in a separate comment. Thank you

Comment: For Each myField In sourceDocument.TablesOfContents(1).Range.Fields
        If counter <> 0 Then
           header = myField.result.Text
           Debug.Print header
           Total = a + header + f
           Documents.Open FileName:=Total, ReadOnly:=True
               Set myWindow = Windows(1)
               winNum = myWindow.Index
               If Windows.Count >= 2 Then
                   ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0).Select
                   Selection.WholeStory
                   ActiveDocument.Range(WholeStory).Copy
                   myWindow.Close

Comment: If counter = 1 Then
                        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToFirst
                        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToRelative, Count:=1
                   Else
                        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext
                        Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToLine, Which:=wdGoToRelative, Count:=1
                   End If

                 Selection.Range.Paste
 
                 End If
        End If
      DoEvents
      counter = counter + 1
    Next
 
 

End Sub

Comment: I had to send it in two halve, I hope it makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Edit that code into your question, it is too hard to read in the comments

Comment: Hi Salek, I am rally sorry about that. I have put it into my original question now. Thanks

Comment: Hi Salek, the Selection.Range.Print towards the bottom of the code

Comment: Hi Salek, the Selection.Range.Paste towards the bottom of the code pastes the contents of a file, which is in the form of a numbers list. However, the numbering continues from the previous heading. I have recorded a macro and put it in under the line Selection.Range.Paste but it just restarts the first number but the second just continues from the previous list. I have also added this recorded macro now in my original question. Thank you.